# Oracle - Determine maximum supported size for regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a regular expression that throws ORA-12733, "regular expression is too long". How do I determine what the maximum supported size is?

FYI: the offending regex is 892 characters. It's a generated regex, so I could change how I generate and execute it, but I would like to know what the limits to the max size are before I change how I am generating and executing.

(running Oracle 10.2g)

**UPDATE:**

If it depends on the actual regex, here's the begining of it (the rest is just the same thing repeated, with different values between `^` and `$`):

`(^R_1A$|^R_2A$|^R_3A$|^R_4A$|^R_4B$|^R_5A$|^R_5B$`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for the regex functions, REGEXP_SUBSTR, REGEXP_INSTR & REGEXP_REPLACE it has the following quote for the pattern:

> pattern is the regular expression. It is usually a text
>   literal and can be of any of the
>   datatypes CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or
>   NVARCHAR2. **It can contain up to 512
>   bytes**. If the datatype of pattern is
>   different from the datatype of
>   source_char, Oracle Database converts
>   pattern to the datatype of
>   source_char. For a listing of the
>   operators you can specify in
>   pattern`**

Taken from [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm#i1305521)

Comment: Aha, so it's 512 bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The sample regex should not need all the start/end of line anchors. `^(R_1A|R_2A|R_3A|R_4A|R_4B|R_5A|R_5B)$` would work just as fine.

Actually: If the search tokens are really as similar as in the sample, one might want to benefit from it with `^(R_[1-5]A|R_[4-5]B)$` or `^(R_([1-5]A|[4-5]B))$` (for the search string's part given in the question).

Verified in 11.2:

```
SELECT i, t FROM (
  SELECT 1 i, 'R_1A' t FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,   'xR_2A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,   'R_3Ax'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,   'xR_4Ax' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,   'R_4B'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,   'R_5A'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7,   'R_5B'   FROM DUAL)
--WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t, '(^R_1A$|^R_2A$|^R_3A$|^R_4A$|^R_4B$|^R_5A$|^R_5B$)')
--WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t, '^(R_1A|R_2A|R_3A|R_4A|R_4B|R_5A|R_5B)$')
--WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t, '^(R_[1-5]A|R_[4-5]B)$')
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t, '^(R_([1-5]A|[4-5]B))$')
ORDER BY i;
```