# Does java.net.Inet6Address.getByName Literally Go Out and See if the Address Exists

Tags: java, oracle, ipv6

I don't know java but as you can see from this question (**[Oracle Regular Expression (REGEXP_LIKE) Too Long Error - ORA-12733](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921658/oracle-regular-expression-regexp-like-too-long-error-ora-12733)**) java seems to be the easiest to accomplish validating if an IPv6 address is formatted correctly.  I tried regular expressions, came close, but was a nightmare, and the expression is too long for PL/SQL.

I have the java in Oracle way working.  I only want to validate the format, not that the address really exists.  So does `java.net.Inet6Address.getByName` literally go out and see if the address exists?

The documentation says... (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String))

"*If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked.*"

I'm taking that as it does NOT ping, am I understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a correct understanding - it does *not* issue an [ICMP PING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29).

However, it *must* "Go Out" to *resolve the host-name* (via [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)).

Of course, when an IP literal supplied, then there is no need to resolve as such .. Use this method only if attempting a name resolve is OK/desired. Be wary when using it to generally check for the validity of an IP literal.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, just check for a valid IPv6 format.  `java.net.Inet6Address.getByName` seems to work great, all tests passed.  What should I do to just test the format? Please don't say regexp :)  been down that path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631669/regular-expression-regex-for-ipv6-separate-from-ipv4

Comment: @gfrobenius It *will* work - but it *will* also "Go Out" when such an address is not IPv6. If that's OK with you, then that's OK. Anyway, consider asking a [new] question about how to check for an IPv6 address in a way that *is* compatible with your environment/restrictions. Note that the "ORA error" question linked is about an Oracle DB regular expression and not about a Java regular expression. I'd just use a regular expression (or some tested code that someone else wrote) *behind* a method and call it a day.