# How can I get multiple listagg rows for a certain number of records?

Tags: sql, oracle

As you probably know, [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) allows you to concatenate values from multiple rows into a single value.

I'm trying to build a regular expression from multiple rows, and then extract it to be used in other applications to search for files.

However, [there is a limit on the maximum length of regular expressions in Oracle (512 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694023/oracle-determine-maximum-supported-size-for-regular-expression).

For this reason, I need to get multiple rows with a separate listagg, and then export that output.

```
--The output I need is multiple rows with a listagg on 50 rows each

select '^.*(' || listagg(id, '|') within group (order by id) || ')' regex
from mytable
--where rownum < 50
```

Here's where I'm stuck. Is it possible?

Comment: Solved it! select distinct '^.*(' || listagg(id, '|') within group (order by id) over (partition by floor(rownum / 50)) || ')'  regex
from mytable

Comment: Done, but I can't repost the snippet due to some bug. It's the same one in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other aggregate functions, [`listagg` also supports analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030). So, we can partition it by values. `floor(rownum/50)` gives the same value for 50 consecutive rows.

```
select distinct '^.*(' || listagg(id, '|') within group (order by id)
    over (partition by floor(rownum / 50)) || ')' regex
from mytable
```